# How to Deserialize Json in Visual Basic 2013?

Tags: json, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, json-deserialization

I am trying to insert deserialized json data into sqlite table in Visual Basic 2013. But, I am facing problem in Deserializing json data. Json data structure is as follows -

```
[
{
"QID":"1",
"Question_Text":"This is a demo question",
"Question_Media":null,
"Subject_Id":"1",
"Subject_Name":"Demo Subject",
"Topic_Id":"12",
"Topic_Name":"Demo Topic",
"Chapter_No":"11",
"Exam_Id":"58",
"Exam_Name":"Demo Exam",
"Explanation":"Demo Explanation",
"Explanation_Media":null,
"Reference":null,
"Option_01":"Lesser petrosal nerve",
"Option_01_Media":null,
"Option_01_isCorrect":"0",
"Option_01_Hint":null,
"Option_01_Hint_Media":null,
"Option_02":"Maxillary nerve",
"Option_02_Media":null,
"Option_02_isCorrect":"1",
"Option_02_Hint":null,
"Option_02_Hint_Media":null,
"Option_03":"Motor root of trigeminal nerve",
"Option_03_Media":null,
"Option_03_isCorrect":"0",
"Option_03_Hint":null,
"Option_03_Hint_Media":null,
"Option_04":"Sensory branch of mandibular nerve",
"Option_04_Media":null,
"Option_04_isCorrect":"0",
"Option_04_Hint":null,
"Option_04_Hint_Media":null,
"Option_05":null,
"Option_05_Media":null,
"Option_05_isCorrect":"0",
"Option_05_Hint":null,
"Option_05_Hint_Media":null,
"Option_06":null,
"Option_06_Media":null,
"Option_06_isCorrect":"0",
"Option_06_Hint":null,
"Option_06_Hint_Media":null,
"Added_By":"demo",
"Question_Type":"1",
"Created_At":"2015-03-07 22:58:01",
"Updated_At":"2015-03-14 22:56:08",
"DID":"0",
"Exams":null,
"Difficulty_Level":"1",
"isVerified":"0",
"isDuplicate":"0",
"isSeen":"0",
"isAnsweredCorrect":"0",
"isAnsweredWrong":"0",
"isMarked":"0",
"Remarks":null,
"isRepeat":"0",
"NotInExam":"0"
},
{
"QID":"2",
"Question_Text":"Demo question 2",
"Question_Media":null,
"Subject_Id":"1",
"Subject_Name":"Demo subject 2",
"Topic_Id":"12",
"Topic_Name":"Demo topic 2",
"Chapter_No":"11",
"Exam_Id":"58",
"Exam_Name":"Demo exam 2",
"Explanation":"Demo explanation 2",
"Explanation_Media":null,
"Reference":null,
"Option_01":"Hypothalamus",
"Option_01_Media":null,
"Option_01_isCorrect":"0",
"Option_01_Hint":null,
"Option_01_Hint_Media":null,
"Option_02":"Pituitary gland",
"Option_02_Media":null,
"Option_02_isCorrect":"1",
"Option_02_Hint":null,
"Option_02_Hint_Media":null,
"Option_03":"Amygdaloid body",
"Option_03_Media":null,
"Option_03_isCorrect":"0",
"Option_03_Hint":null,
"Option_03_Hint_Media":null,
"Option_04":"Basal ganglia ",
"Option_04_Media":null,
"Option_04_isCorrect":"0",
"Option_04_Hint":null,
"Option_04_Hint_Media":null,
"Option_05":null,
"Option_05_Media":null,
"Option_05_isCorrect":"0",
"Option_05_Hint":null,
"Option_05_Hint_Media":null,
"Option_06":null,
"Option_06_Media":null,
"Option_06_isCorrect":"0",
"Option_06_Hint":null,
"Option_06_Hint_Media":null,
"Added_By":"demo",
"Question_Type":"1",
"Created_At":"2015-03-07 22:59:15",
"Updated_At":"2015-03-14 21:42:12",
"DID":"0",
"Exams":null,
"Difficulty_Level":"1",
"isVerified":"0",
"isDuplicate":"0",
"isSeen":"0",
"isAnsweredCorrect":"0",
"isAnsweredWrong":"0",
"isMarked":"0",
"Remarks":null,
"isRepeat":"0",
"NotInExam":"0"
}
]
```

My code so far (on button click) is -

```
Dim request As HttpWebRequest
Dim response As HttpWebResponse = Nothing
Dim reader As StreamReader
Dim rawresp As String
Dim URL As String
URL = "http://localhost/json/question.php"
Try
request = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(URL), HttpWebRequest)
response = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
reader = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
rawresp = reader.ReadToEnd()
'Everything works fine until here, but error occurs as soon as I write following code
Dim jsonQuestions As JSON_Questions = _
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of JSON_Questions)(rawresp.ToString)

Catch ex As Exception
TextBox1.Text = ex.ToString
Finally
If Not response Is Nothing Then response.Close()
End Try
```

But it is throwing following error -

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the
>   current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type
>   'Quiz_Maker.JSON_Questions' because the type requires a JSON object
>   (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly. To fix this error
>   either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or
>   change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a
>   collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can
>   be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be
>   added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array. Path
>   '', line 1, position 1.    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.EnsureArrayContract(JsonReader
>   reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract)    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateList(JsonReader
>   reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member,
>   Object existingValue, String id)    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader
>   reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member,
>   JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember,
>   Object existingValue)    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader
>   reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader,
>   Type objectType)    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type
>   objectType)    at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String
>   value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value,
>   JsonSerializerSettings settings)    at
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value)    at
>   Quiz_Maker.Advanced_Settings.btnResetQuestions_Click(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e) in C:\VisualStudioProjects\Quiz Maker\Quiz Maker\Quiz
>   Maker\Advanced Settings.vb:line 25

After reading on net and stackoverflow's similar questions, I made the `JSON_Questions` class as follows -

```
Public Class JSON_Questions
    Public Property QID() As String
        Get
            Return m_QID
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_QID = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_QID As String
    Public Property Question_Text() As String
        Get
            Return m_Question_Text
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_Question_Text = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Question_Text As String
    Public Property Question_Media() As Object
        Get
            Return m_Question_Media
        End Get
        Set(value As Object)
            m_Question_Media = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Question_Media As Object
    Public Property Subject_Id() As String
        Get
            Return m_Subject_Id
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_Subject_Id = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Subject_Id As String
    Public Property Subject_Name() As String
        Get
            Return m_Subject_Name
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_Subject_Name = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Subject_Name As String
    Public Property Topic_Id() As String
        Get
            Return m_Topic_Id
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_Topic_Id = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Topic_Id As String
    Public Property Topic_Name() As String
        Get
            Return m_Topic_Name
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_Topic_Name = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Topic_Name As String
    Public Property Chapter_No() As String
        Get
            Return m_Chapter_No
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_Chapter_No = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Chapter_No As String
    Public Property Exam_Id() As String
        Get
            Return m_Exam_Id
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_Exam_Id = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Exam_Id As String
    Public Property Exam_Name() As String
        Get
            Return m_Exam_Name
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_Exam_Name = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Exam_Name As String
    Public Property Explanation() As String
        Get
            Return m_Explanation
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_Explanation = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Explanation As String
    Public Property Explanation_Media() As Object
        Get
            Return m_Explanation_Media
        End Get
        Set(value As Object)
            m_Explanation_Media = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Explanation_Media As Object
    Public Property Reference() As Object
        Get
            Return m_Reference
        End Get
        Set(value As Object)
            m_Reference = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Reference As Object
    Public Property Option_01() As String
        Get
            Return m_Option_01
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_Option_01 = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Option_01 As String
    Public Property Option_01_Media() As Object
        Get
            Return m_Option_01_Media
        End Get
        Set(value As Object)
            m_Option_01_Media = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Option_01_Media As Object
    Public Property Option_01_isCorrect() As String
        Get
            Return m_Option_01_isCorrect
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_Option_01_isCorrect = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Option_01_isCorrect As String
    Public Property Option_01_Hint() As String
        Get
            Return m_Option_01_Hint
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_Option_01_Hint = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Option_01_Hint As String
    Public Property Option_01_Hint_Media() As Object
        Get
            Return m_Option_01_Hint_Media
        End Get
        Set(value As Object)
            m_Option_01_Hint_Media = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Option_01_Hint_Media As Object
    Public Property Option_02() As String
        Get
            Return m_Option_02
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_Option_02 = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Option_02 As String
    Public Property Option_02_Media() As Object
        Get
            Return m_Option_02_Media
        End Get
        Set(value As Object)
            m_Option_02_Media = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Option_02_Media As Object
    Public Property Option_02_isCorrect() As String
        Get
            Return m_Option_02_isCorrect
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_Option_02_isCorrect = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Option_02_isCorrect As String
    Public Property Option_02_Hint() As Object
        Get
            Return m_Option_02_Hint
        End Get
        Set(value As Object)
            m_Option_02_Hint = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Option_02_Hint As Object
    Public Property Option_02_Hint_Media() As Object
        Get
            Return m_Option_02_Hint_Media
        End Get
        Set(value As Object)
            m_Option_02_Hint_Media = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Option_02_Hint_Media As Object
    Public Property Option_03() As String
        Get
            Return m_Option_03
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_Option_03 = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Option_03 As String
    Public Property Option_03_Media() As Object
        Get
            Return m_Option_03_Media
        End Get
        Set(value As Object)
            m_Option_03_Media = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Option_03_Media As Object
    Public Property Option_03_isCorrect() As String
        Get
            Return m_Option_03_isCorrect
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_Option_03_isCorrect = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Option_03_isCorrect As String
    Public Property Option_03_Hint() As Object
        Get
            Return m_Option_03_Hint
        End Get
        Set(value As Object)
            m_Option_03_Hint = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Option_03_Hint As Object
    Public Property Option_03_Hint_Media() As Object
        Get
            Return m_Option_03_Hint_Media
        End Get
        Set(value As Object)
            m_Option_03_Hint_Media = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Option_03_Hint_Media As Object
    Public Property Option_04() As String
        Get
            Return m_Option_04
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_Option_04 = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Option_04 As String
    Public Property Option_04_Media() As Object
        Get
            Return m_Option_04_Media
        End Get
        Set(value As Object)
            m_Option_04_Media = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Option_04_Media As Object
    Public Property Option_04_isCorrect() As String
        Get
            Return m_Option_04_isCorrect
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_Option_04_isCorrect = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Option_04_isCorrect As String
    Public Property Option_04_Hint() As Object
        Get
            Return m_Option_04_Hint
        End Get
        Set(value As Object)
            m_Option_04_Hint = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Option_04_Hint As Object
    Public Property Option_04_Hint_Media() As Object
        Get
            Return m_Option_04_Hint_Media
        End Get
        Set(value As Object)
            m_Option_04_Hint_Media = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Option_04_Hint_Media As Object
    Public Property Option_05() As String
        Get
            Return m_Option_05
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_Option_05 = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Option_05 As String
    Public Property Option_05_Media() As Object
        Get
            Return m_Option_05_Media
        End Get
        Set(value As Object)
            m_Option_05_Media = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Option_05_Media As Object
    Public Property Option_05_isCorrect() As String
        Get
            Return m_Option_05_isCorrect
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_Option_05_isCorrect = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Option_05_isCorrect As String
    Public Property Option_05_Hint() As Object
        Get
            Return m_Option_05_Hint
        End Get
        Set(value As Object)
            m_Option_05_Hint = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Option_05_Hint As Object
    Public Property Option_05_Hint_Media() As Object
        Get
            Return m_Option_05_Hint_Media
        End Get
        Set(value As Object)
            m_Option_05_Hint_Media = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Option_05_Hint_Media As Object
    Public Property Option_06() As String
        Get
            Return m_Option_06
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_Option_06 = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Option_06 As String
    Public Property Option_06_Media() As Object
        Get
            Return m_Option_06_Media
        End Get
        Set(value As Object)
            m_Option_06_Media = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Option_06_Media As Object
    Public Property Option_06_isCorrect() As String
        Get
            Return m_Option_06_isCorrect
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_Option_06_isCorrect = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Option_06_isCorrect As String
    Public Property Option_06_Hint() As Object
        Get
            Return m_Option_06_Hint
        End Get
        Set(value As Object)
            m_Option_06_Hint = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Option_06_Hint As Object
    Public Property Option_06_Hint_Media() As Object
        Get
            Return m_Option_06_Hint_Media
        End Get
        Set(value As Object)
            m_Option_06_Hint_Media = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Option_06_Hint_Media As Object
    Public Property Added_By() As String
        Get
            Return m_Added_By
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_Added_By = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Added_By As String
    Public Property Question_Type() As String
        Get
            Return m_Question_Type
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_Question_Type = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Question_Type As String
    Public Property Created_At() As String
        Get
            Return m_Created_At
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_Created_At = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Created_At As String
    Public Property Updated_At() As String
        Get
            Return m_Updated_At
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_Updated_At = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Updated_At As String
    Public Property DID() As String
        Get
            Return m_DID
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_DID = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_DID As String
    Public Property Exams() As String
        Get
            Return m_Exams
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_Exams = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Exams As String
    Public Property Difficulty_Level() As String
        Get
            Return m_Difficulty_Level
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_Difficulty_Level = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Difficulty_Level As String
    Public Property isVerified() As String
        Get
            Return m_isVerified
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_isVerified = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_isVerified As String
    Public Property isDuplicate() As String
        Get
            Return m_isDuplicate
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_isDuplicate = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_isDuplicate As String
    Public Property isSeen() As String
        Get
            Return m_isSeen
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_isSeen = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_isSeen As String
    Public Property isAnsweredCorrect() As String
        Get
            Return m_isAnsweredCorrect
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_isAnsweredCorrect = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_isAnsweredCorrect As String
    Public Property isAnsweredWrong() As String
        Get
            Return m_isAnsweredWrong
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_isAnsweredWrong = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_isAnsweredWrong As String
    Public Property isMarked() As String
        Get
            Return m_isMarked
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_isMarked = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_isMarked As String
    Public Property Remarks() As Object
        Get
            Return m_Remarks
        End Get
        Set(value As Object)
            m_Remarks = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Remarks As Object
    Public Property isRepeat() As String
        Get
            Return m_isRepeat
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_isRepeat = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_isRepeat As String
    Public Property NotInExam() As String
        Get
            Return m_NotInExam
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_NotInExam = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_NotInExam As String
End Class
```

Previously, I was using the class as follows -

```
Public Class JSON_Questions
    Public QID As Integer
    Public Question_Text As String
    Public Subject_Id As Integer
    Public Subject_Name As String
    Public Topic_Id As Integer
    Public Topic_Name As String
    Public Chapter_No As Integer
    Public Exam_Id As Integer
    Public Exam_Name As String
    Public Explanation As String
    Public Option_01 As String
    Public Option_01_isCorrect As Integer
    Public Option_02 As String
    Public Option_02_isCorrect As Integer
    Public Option_03 As String
    Public Option_03_isCorrect As Integer
    Public Option_04 As String
    Public Option_04_isCorrect As Integer
    Public Option_05 As String
    Public Option_05_isCorrect As Integer
    Public Option_06 As String
    Public Option_06_isCorrect As Integer
    Public Added_By As String
    Public Question_Type As Integer
    Public Created_At As String
    Public Updated_At As String
    'Public Json_Result As String
End Class
```

I have even tried `JObject` and `List(of JToken)` -

```
Dim jResults As JObject = JObject.Parse(rawresp)
Dim results As List(Of JToken) = jResults.Children().ToList()
```

But, none of the above seems to be working. **I am stuck here for more than 2 days, but could not figure out how to Deserialize this Json and insert into sqlite table.**

Comment: according to www.jsonlint.com, it isnt valid Json. `"This is a demo question"",` has an extra trailing quote

Comment: Why do you use `WebRequest.Create(URL)` instead of `HttpWebRequest.Create(URL)`?

Comment: @Plutonix the json is generated in php using `$json=json_encode($resultArray);` I am posting my php code too.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895105/deserialize-json-with-c-sharp

Comment: Your JSON is not corret formatted, some line have 2 quotes "" at end .. like Question_text, Like @Plutonix said !

Comment: not sure who, what or where it was created matters, `"Question_Text":"This is a demo question"",` is invalid - note the extra quote and note how SO chokes on syntax highlighting at that point.

Comment: @Plutonix sorry that was my mistake while creating this question. In reality  my question text was very long, so i replaced that demo text in notepad before pasting here. In reality wherever extra `"` is used, it's used as `\"` (with a backslash)

Comment: @CristiC777 that double quote was my mistake, while creating this question. (otherwise every extra double quote is `\"` format). I have corrected it now, with edited question (posted php code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key part of the error message is:

> change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List

Either of these 2 ways works fine with the corrected data:

```
' get a List<T>
Dim myQAs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of JSON_Questions))(jstr)

' deser to an array:
Dim myQAs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of JSON_Questions())(jstr)
```

The Json posted contains *two* questions which is why the error message is saying it needs an array r List.  Now when deserialized it is in an array or List depending on which one you use, so to access your data:

```
thisQ = myQAs(0).Question_Text
```

Once you type the dot, Intellisense will display the field and you can pick what you want.

The whole thing would be easier to work with if `Option_01`...etc were a collection or array of Option rather than spelled out over and over and over.

Comment: Your code seems to be working, but now I am unable to get column/rows from variable `jd`  to insert into sqlite previously I was able to use `jsonQuestion.QID` and so on. and yes you are right, it would be easier if I had array of Option, it would be easier, but being a medical doctor, right now I am not able to give proper time to learn these.

Comment: well **now** they are in an array or list, so use `jd(0).QID`  Intellisense will guide you

Comment: thanks for your patience,  I got it now, and sorry for more questions. but 2 last questions - **1** which one should I use - `list` or `array`, because both are working fine for me and I don't know their pros and cons. and **2** (somewhat off-topic) as I am inserting this json output into sqlite, would there be any faster way. At present I am looping row by row. But it's taking lot of time for 10k questions. thanks.

Comment: Sorry I really wanted to even without your mention, I was searching about `difference between webrequest and httpwebrequest`.. I just upvoted it

Comment: that actually seems like it could be a good question all by itself.  not sure if there isnt already an answer here somewhere though.  Subtleties between them is not my strong suit

Answer (score 0):

Here is the key:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type
>   'Quiz_Maker.JSON_Questions' because the type requires a JSON object

The deserializer expects a JSON object, but you are passing a JSON array. Simply remove the square brackets at the beginning and at the end, and your code should start working.

Or you can also use

```
Dim jResults As JArray = JArray.Parse(rawresp)
```

instead of

```
Dim jResults As JObject = JObject.Parse(rawresp)
```

Hope this helps, although it's untested.

Comment: the step `Dim jResults As JArray` was working for me, but it was not being helpful in further deserializing. While at the same time Plutonix's answer worked for me.